# How to convert the Date data of List<javebean> into SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, dao

I have a List, and the Date data format is as follows:

```
List = [["Mon Jun 24 09:20:36 CST 2019",1],["Wed Jul 03 14:28:38 CST 2019",2],["Mon Jun 24 17:04:54 CST 2019",1],["Mon Jul 15 16:00:13 CST 2019",1],["Wed Jun 26 11:35:01 CST 2019",1],["Tue Jul 16 10:21:59 CST 2019",0],["Wed Jul 03 14:44:08 CST 2019",1],["Fri Jul 12 17:18:21 CST 2019",1],["Wed Jul 03 15:59:08 CST 2019",1],["Fri Jul 12 15:43:05 CST 2019",0],["Tue Jul 16 14:05:49 CST 2019",1],["Tue Jun 25 10:58:49 CST 2019",1],["Fri Jul 12 15:40:46 CST 2019",0],["Wed Jul 03 15:28:34 CST 2019",1],["Mon Jun 24 15:47:07 CST 2019",0],["Wed Jul 03 16:59:08 CST 2019",1],["Wed Jul 03 17:06:11 CST 2019",1]]
```

I want to change the date inside to "yyyy-mm-dd" and sort by date in ascending order, removing duplicate dates.

I use JAVA8, Struts2 and Oracle DB.

My code:

```
List<Event> eventList = eventDao.getAll();

Entity
Table(name = "EVENT")

   NamedQuery(name = "Event.findByStime", query = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.stime = :stime")
```

Comment: This post is going to close, please edit the post with minimal example and also with your effort

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The point is even more valid in Java 8, where java.time is built-in.

Comment: Use a `LocalDate` for the date. Its `toString` method gives you the `yyyy-mm-dd` format that you are asking for. Put your beans into a `TreeMap` with the date as key, and it will sort them for you and remove duplicates. Or a `TreeSet` with a comparator comparing the dates.

Answer (score 0):

//test pojo class

```
public class TimeAndInt {

    private Date date;
    private int number;
    private String dateString;

    public TimeAndInt(Date date, int number) {
        this.date = date;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

//test main class

```
public class TestMain {


    private static String DateToStringFormat(Date date, String pattern){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TimeAndInt> list = new ArrayList<TimeAndInt>();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        Date date1 = calendar.getTime();

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(new Date());
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);
        Date date2 = calendar2.getTime();

        list.add(new TimeAndInt(new Date(),2));
        list.add(new TimeAndInt(date1,1));
        list.add(new TimeAndInt(date2,0));

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<TimeAndInt>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TimeAndInt t1, TimeAndInt t2) {
                return t1.getDate().compareTo(t2.getDate());
            }
        });

        for (TimeAndInt timeAndInt : list) {
            timeAndInt.setDateString(DateToStringFormat(timeAndInt.getDate(),"yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

in applicaiton use `comparator` can resolve problem

Answer (score -1):

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse("Mon Jun 24 09:20:36 CST 2019", formatter);
d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

Comment: Probably useful code and demonstrating the use of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, thanks. You need to explain how it fits into the questioner’s situation and whether and how it may solve his or her problem. Code-only answers are not helpful.